# Is anyMatch deterministic like filter + findFirst?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is anyMatch deterministic (for an ordered stream) like filter + findFirst?
Are there any other differences beside the returning value?

If I have an ordered stream asList("a","b","c").filter(predicate).findFirst() it is guaranteed that the predicate will be evaluated for each element of the stream in the given order ("a" than "b" than "c") until one will match (findFirst). I am wondering if asList("a","b","c").anyMatch(predicate) will also evaluate the predicate in the given order ("a" than "b" than "c")?

Comment: I presume you mean filter + findFirst + isPresent?

Comment: I am interested on the deterministic aspect

Comment: @telebog Could you explain how do you mean .`filter(...).findFirst()` is deterministic? An example to illustrate would be really good. Besides `anyMatch` and `findFirst`, both serve quite different purposes.

Comment: @Naman I updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much to be deterministic about here; at least the comparison you are asking for makes little sense. `filter.findFirst` will return an `Optional<T>`, so if you care about *which* element was found, is it really first for an ordered stream? If so, the answer is yes - but it seems you are already aware of that.

In case of `anyMatch` - the determinism is only about the result, which is a `boolean`, so there is not much to be deterministic about, really; be that for an ordered stream or not. The result will "deterministically" be `true/false` - that is the only guarantee you get.

If your question whether the stream will be *traversed* from the beginning or not in case of `anyMatch` is an entirely different question. That is an implementation detail, of course; but it does not have to be traversed that way. The stream internals could easily have different paths that are taken in case of `anyMatch`: a totally made-up example, but entirely possible:

```
Stream.of(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
      .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
      .anyMatch(x -> x > 4);
```

A stream internal could keep "in mind" that the min for this stream is `1` and the max is `6`, for this `anyMatch` is could take `6` and test is against `max`, if that matches, you are done. So the comparison could happen against the last element - `6`, which would be different then `filter.findFirst` - `5`.

I highly doubt that such optimizations (that might probably even hurt more than "optimize") would ever be done; but in theory could be possible.

Comment: It’s more likely for an implementation to skip the sorting operation, as the terminal operation is unordered. That’s easier to check and even yields a bigger improvement.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene indeed I was curios if anymatch evaluates the stream in the natural order until it founds an element that match the predicate. So for your example filter.findFirst will evaluate in the following order 1,2,3,4,5 and it stops. Can you tell me why do you think that anymatch will not evaluate the element in the same order (1,2,3,4,5 and it stops)? Reading the java doc From the Stream class I don't have any reason to believe that.

Comment: @telebog exactly. the java-doc does not tell you _anything_, on purpose; thus leaves room for _any_ type of implementation it might find appropriate, be that just like `filter.findFirst` or like in the made-up example that I made. Think about it : if all you care is the result of `anyMatch` - do you care which path was taken internally?

Comment: Yes makes sense. But then I should also assume that filter can not respect the order too.

Comment: @telebog you have to make a clear distinction between `terminal` and `intermediate` operations. `anyMatch` _is_ terminal, `filter` is _not_. for a `parallel` stream, `filter` _might_ get executed out of order, but terminal operations are stipulated in the java-doc (well, almost). There are multiple answers I personally gave on these kind of questions too...

Answer (score 4):

`anyMatch` returns `boolean` value `true` if any elements of the stream match the provided predicate, otherwise returns `false` where as `findFirst` returns you `Optional<T>` which will contain the matching element if it exist else will return empty Optional. You can choose based on what you are trying to do. If you just want to check if the value exist or not then you can use `anyMatch` as it gives you the value. If you want to find the value and do something with it, you can use `findFirst`. Following is a small code snippet showing both goes in exact same fashion when used with `stream` the approach is not predictable when used with `parallelStream`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyInteger> myIntegers= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            myIntegers.add(new MyInteger(i));
        }
        System.err.println("----------findFirst------------");
        Optional<MyInteger> result = myIntegers.stream().filter(m -> m.equals(5)).findFirst();
        if(result.isPresent()){
            System.err.println("Matching Record Found: " + result.get());
        }else {
            System.err.println("Matching Record Not Found.");
        }

        System.err.println("----------anyMatch------------");
        System.err.println("anyMatch Result: " + myIntegers.stream().anyMatch(m -> m.equals(5)));
    }
}

class MyInteger {
    private int number;

    public MyInteger(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyInteger{" +
                "number=" + number +
                '}';
    }

    boolean equals(int match){
        System.err.println("Matching " + number + " with " + match);
        return number == match;
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
----------findFirst------------
Matching 1 with 5
Matching 2 with 5
Matching 3 with 5
Matching 4 with 5
Matching 5 with 5
Matching Record Found: MyInteger{number=5}
----------anyMatch------------
Matching 1 with 5
Matching 2 with 5
Matching 3 with 5
Matching 4 with 5
Matching 5 with 5
anyMatch Result: true
```

Comment: I am interested on the deterministic aspect

Answer (score 1):

Stream **anyMatch** function returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided predicate. **It may not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result.** This is a short-circuiting terminal operation, which returns a boolean value.

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(3, 1);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 12, 20);
    boolean b = list1.stream().anyMatch(list2::contains);
```

The above statement returns false.

Stream **Filter** return stream of the elements that match the given predicate. This is an intermediate operation. These operations are always lazy i.e, executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream which when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate.

Stream **FindFirst** is a terminal operation. It returns an Optional the first value encountered in the stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty. isPresent is a boolean function that is used to identify if the optional has a value or not.

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(3, 11);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 12, 20);

    Optional<Integer> first = list1.stream().filter(list2::contains).findFirst();
    if(first.isPresent())
        System.out.println(first.get());
```

Comment: I am interested on the deterministic aspect